# extracting security profile specific files RHEL CentOS

Tags: ssh, security, xml, installer-anaconda

during the install of RHEL 7.x or CentOS one can choose (or not choose) to apply one of these security profiles *these are from 7.6*:

- United States Government Configuration Baseline
- Standard System Security Profile for RHEL 7
- Criminal Justice Information Services (CJIS)
- C2S for RHEL 7 {Commercial Cloud Services}
- HIPPA
- Unclassified Information in  non-federal Information System Organizations (NIST 800-171)
- DISA stig for RHEL 7
- OSPP v4.2
- PCI-DSS v3 control baseline for RHEL 7
- Red Hat Corporate profile for certified cloud providers (RHCCP)

In choosing one it changes a myriad of configuration files.  which ones?  I wouldn't mind knowing, but

I want to know if it's possible to extract, simply the **/etc/ssh/sshd_config** file that gets used for a given security profile from an already running RHEL or CentOS system **not** having that profile applied at system creation; I do not want to spend the time installing RHEL/CentOS on a new system disk (10 times) with a profile applied to then extract and save said file(s) to a usb stick for comparison and understanding.

Answer (score 1):

(Disclaimer: I have zero practical experience with scap.)

On the negative side: as far as I can tell, it's not easily possible to do that, since it's not a matter of "this is the non-default config file I'll drop in". As far as I can tell, the definitions are provided by the `scap-security-guide` package, and the profiles are really a big bunch of rules like "no root login", "only these ssh algorithms allowed", etc. So instead of a complete file, we get a whole bunch of incremental changes.

On the positive side: if you look at the above-mentioned package, it'll install, in triplicate (bash, ansible, kickstart), the implementation of the rules into `/usr/share/scap-security-guide`, so you "only" need to look in there. (To give you an idea, the HIPPA role shell script is around 800k.)

On another positive side: looking at `man scap-security-guide`, you should be able to use `oscap` to just compare the existing system against the guidelines, which will give you, vaguely, a long list with either checkmarks or to-dos. RedHat has [a useful guide to using scap](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/sect-using_oscap) to generate these reports.

Comment: The `scap-workbench` graphical tool is an excellent additional resource for putting the `scap-security-guide` information to use; scanning systems against various baselines, generating remediation scripts and playbook, etc.